# Stylesheet switcher in Safari 5.1 WebKit 534

Tags: javascript, stylesheet

I have a stylesheet switcher which works fine in all mainstream browsers until Safari 5.1 and possibly a past version of Chrome. The source of the problem appears to be in WebKit version 534. Other designers have experienced similar problems:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3215084?start=0&tstart=0

This version of WebKit appears not to action:

```
a.disabled  = false
```

in the following script:

```
  function changeLayout(description){
   var i, a;
   for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++){
   if(a.getAttribute("title") == description){a.disabled = false;}
   else if(a.getAttribute("title") != "default"){a.disabled = true;}
}
}
```

(or perhaps it may be the case that it will only allow one active stylesheet, the default?)

I have alternative code I can deliver to switch the stylesheet but it is more onerous and I only want to run it if the usual method would fail.

Is there a way I could test if the browser is respecting
"a.disabled  = false" (or true for that matter)
and then deliver the alternative code if not?

OR is there a reliable way to test for WebKit version 534?

Answer (score 0):

I know jQuery.Browser can detect things like webkit and versions. Check it out here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

**Edit**

Looks like it is now depricated, replaced with jQuery.Support:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/